# Reproducible crawling behavior with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

How can I make the [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/) crawler reproducible? By reproducibility, I mean that if we crawl the same website twice, we crawl it in exactly the same way. Therefore, we visit pages in the same order each time. Assume the website is static. In fact, if we print the URL in the following function (i.e., `parse`) it should print the same thing each time:

```
class SiteSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ReproducibleSpider'
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse', follow=True)]

    def __init__(self, urls: list[str], domains: list[str]):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_urls = urls
        self.allowed_domain = domains

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        url = response.url if hasattr(response, 'url') else None
        print(url)
        return None
```

I also tried the following piece:

```
class SortedLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def extract_links(self, response):
        links = super().extract_links(response)
        return sorted(links, key=lambda x: len(x.url))
```

I realized that [concurrent request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) in Scrapy is the source of the problem! Any idea how to fix it without sacrificing the performance?

Edit: Specifying the [concurrency](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain) with the following setup gives me some reproducibility:

```
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' = 1
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN' = 1
```

Comment: Why would this matter?!

Comment: I have a deduplication pipeline that drops some pages. If I crawl a website twice there is a chance to have duplicate pages.

Comment: why not wait until you've finished fetching from some root and then put the resulting urls into some canonical order?

Comment: There is no way to do this without sacrificing at least some performance.

Comment: Could you get anywhere using something like https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order maybe with a custom priority queue if this leaves too much on the floor?